# Set Data roaming on/off

Tags: android

How could I programmatically set data roaming on/off in my android application ?

Comment: Interesting question... the only thing I have found is how to know whether roaming is enabled or not: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#isNetworkRoaming()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data roaming is currently on, then I think you can manipulate the Access Points Names in order to make it appear that a data service isn't available.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775771/access-point-name-manipulation-in-android) which also links to [apndroid](http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/).  You could browse their source and see the approach they have taken.

If data roaming has been set to off by the user, then this approach won't work.  Though you could prompt users to turn it on as part of your install/setup process, which is the route apndroid take.

apndroid also provide an [API](http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/wiki/API) for changing these kind of settings, which might be more convenient than reimplementing the same functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Apologies in advance for reopening a dead post but I have managed to achieve it by calling this executable:

`su -c settings  put  global  data_roaming0  1`

Also to get the roaming setting for first SIM card:

`su -c settings  get  global  data_roaming0`

Answer (score 3):

If your app is signatureOrSystem/Privileged app (app resides in /system/priv-app) and your have valid android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission in system/etc/permissions. Then you can do it as below.

**Enable :**

```
Settings.Global.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DATA_ROAMING, 1)
```

**Disable :**

```
Settings.Global.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DATA_ROAMING, 0)
```

Comment: I get this error on a device-owner app (dedicated device): `Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` - shouldn't it be considered a privileged app?

Answer (score 1):

I hope that it's not possible to turn on data roaming **programmatically** as this would be a serious security issue from my point of view ...
Data roaming (i.e. UMTS data transfer via a foreign network) may result in a **huge** bill from your network provider - at least in europe.

Answer (score 0):

On rooted devices when using su to enable data roaming, on multi sim devices the data roaming setting is sim specific.

So you need to get the sim number that is active for data calls

`sim_num = settings get global multi_sim_data_call`

and use this in the data_roaming + sim_num setting. EG sim_num 3

`settings get global data_roaming3`

if this is null then not multi sim device and use data_roaming otherwise use

`settings put global data_roaming3`

Comment: You don't necessarily have to be rooted, you can do this by enabling the _Security settings_ in the USB debugging configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enable data roaming on my dual sim Motorola G8 without the need to root it via ADB. I'm posting here the procedure, because the phone has a bug that prevents data roaming from being enabled normally.

1. You need a computer and to install [ADB installed](https://www.xda-developers.com/quickly-install-adb/amp/)
2. [Enable developer mode and USB debugging](https://www.xda-developers.com/quickly-install-adb/amp/) in your phone
3. Connect the phone to the computer via USB and accept the debugging connection.
4. Start an "adb shell", be sure that it is correctly connected to your phone.
5. Issue the command

> `settings  put  global  data_roaming1  1`

to enable data roaming for SIM card 1, or

> `settings  put  global  data_roaming2  1`

to enable it for SIM 2

Note: if you do not have the USB cable, this can be done via wifi, but the pairing process is a [bit complicated and version dependent](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/set-up-wireless-debugging-android-11-send-adb-commands-without-usb-cable-0302898/).

If you do not have a computer, it may be possible to run the commands directly on the phone using a "local adb" app (there are a few on the play store), but I have not tested any.