# Disabling Android Data/Roaming programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, roaming

I'm currently working on an app, that automatically disables your data connection, when you're in a country that isn't covered by your carrier for data roaming.

Now I'd like to know how I would be able to disable the data connection on android version 4.4+ (I know I can use reflection on lower versions [How to enable mobile data on/off programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817552/how-to-enable-mobile-data-on-off-programmatically) ) just so that the additional charges wouldn't occur when you're travelling.

I know I can just show the notification, but when someone switches towers, the data still gets pulled from the tower, even if the notification is shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Data roaming on/off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773265/set-data-roaming-on-off)

Comment: I think you might be right, I'll take a look at it tomorrow. Thanks!